# One and unlimited times makes lazy search stop

Tags: regex

I have this sentence :

`<i>foo 42 </i> <i>(bar)</i>`

If i try to match it with this regex:

`<i>(foo \d+\s*.+?)(\(bar\))`

The group 1 of the result is:

`foo 42 </i> <i>`

However, if I put a `?` at the end of the regex like this because `(bar)` may or may not be there:

`<i>(foo \d+\s*.+?)(\(bar\))?`

The group 1 of the result becomes:

`foo 42 <`

How can i get `foo 42 </i> <i>` with having the `?` quantifier for the `(bar)` group?

Thank you

Comment: Are you trying to parse html with regex? You get that match because if you make `(\(bar\))?` optional this part `\s*.+?` matches a space and `<` due to the + and ?. Why not match then closing and the opening tag?

Comment: Please describe in words what you want. Getting everything before `(bar)` when `(bar)` is not there makes no sense.

Comment: I am trying to get everything before `(bar)` because there may be important info between `</i>` and `<i>` of  `foo 42 </i> <i>` that I want to keep in my first group.

Comment: You have a lazy quantifier on your `.+` so it will only take _as much as it needs to_. You then make `(bar)` optional. So why would the engine take any more? You've told it to be lazy and it is - you need to think more carefully about what you're trying to match. Obviously if you make your `.+` greedy it will grab absolutely everything in the case `(bar)` is missing. So the real question becomes, when `(bar)` isn't the terminator, what is?

Comment: okay so I understand when the terminator is optional the lazy quantifier will stop as early as possible. I thought it would be more "dynamic" and understand it can continue if the terminator is not here and stop at the terminator if it's here.

Comment: What is the right hand boundary? `</i>`? You must tell the regex where to stop matching, otherwise, it will match either too little or too much.

Comment: Either  https://regex101.com/r/StM4v3/1 or https://regex101.com/r/StM4v3/2 is the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The point is the all optional subpatterns after a lazy dot pattern only match their patterns if this match happens right after one or zero chars.

That is, `<i>(foo \d+\s*.+?)(\(bar\))?` will grab `(bar)` if it follows 0 or more whitespaces and 1 char, like in `<i>foo 42 <(bar)</i>` or `<i>foo 42<(bar)</i>` (see [demo](https://regex101.com/r/yqV3pa/1)).

Since you want to match up to any optional `(bar)`, you need to make sure the `.+?` is turned into a [*tempered greedy token*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37343088/3832970) that can be used with a greedy quantifier, but will be tempered, restricted with a negaitve lookahead:

```
<i>(foo \d+\s*(?:(?!\(bar\)).)*)(\(bar\))?
```

Or, if you need to match the *closest* `foo <digits>` to the `(bar)`:

```
<i>(foo \d+\s*(?:(?!\(bar\)|foo \d).)*)(\(bar\))?
```

See [Regex 1](https://regex101.com/r/StM4v3/1) and [Regex 2](https://regex101.com/r/StM4v3/2) demos.

**Details**

- `<i>` - literal string
- `(foo \d+\s*(?:(?!\(bar\)|foo \d).)*)` - Group 1:

  - `foo \d+` - `foo`, space and 1+ digits
  - `\s*` - 0+ whitespaces
  - `(?:(?!\(bar\)|foo \d).)*` - any char, 0 or more occurrences as many as possible, that does not start a `(bar)` or `foo`, space, a digit char sequences
- `(\(bar\))?` - an optional Group 2: `(bar)` substring.